# Static Field as Null when mocking Enums with PowerMock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have written a Thread Pool and I am not able to write the Junits(PowerMock) for that class.

```
public enum ThreadPool {
INSTANCE;

private static final String THREAD_POOL_SIZE = "threadpool.objectlevel.size";
private static TPropertyReader PROP_READER = new PropertyReader();
private final ExecutorService executorService;
private static final ILogger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ReportExecutorObjectLevelThreadPool.class.getName());

ThreadPool() {
    loadProperties();
    int no_of_threads = getThreadPoolSize();
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(no_of_threads);

}

public void submitTask(Runnable task) {
    executorService.execute(task);
}

private static void loadProperties() {
    try {
        PROP_READER.loadProperties("Dummy");
    } catch (final OODSystemException e) {
        LOGGER.severe("Loading properties for app failed!");
    }
}

private int getThreadPoolSize() {
    return Integer.valueOf(PROP_READER
            .getProperty(THREAD_POOL_SIZE));
}
}
```

While Mocking this class I am getting **NullPointerException** in the line **PROP_READER.loadProperties("DUMMY");**

My Test Case is:-

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(PropertyReader.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockPropertyReader);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when( mockPropertyReader,"loadProperties",anyString());
mockStatic(ThreadPool.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set your internal state of your enum as enum is final class
and the instance of an enum will be load on class loading

```
ThreadPool mockInstance = mock(ThreadPool .class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(ThreadPool.class, "INSTANCE", mockInstance);
```

then

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(ThreadPool .class);
```

and then mocking

```
doNothing().when(mockInstance).loadProperties(any(String.class));
```

do not forget adding the following annotation to the test

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ThreadPool.class})
```

if it still not working you need to see which more member of the class you need to set in the internal state